# Running many multiple OLS regressions at once in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I want to run time series regressions (Fama-French three factor with my new factor). I have following tables.

```
Table01

    Date     Port_01  Port_02 --------- Port_18
    01/1965     0.85    0.97               1.86
    02/1965     8.96    7.2                0.98
    03/1965     8.98    7.9                8.86 

Table 02

    Date        Market   SMB    HML     WXO
    01/1965      0.85    0.97    0.86    0.87
    02/1965      8.96    7.2     0.98    0.79
    03/1965      8.98     7.9    8.86    0.86
```

I have to run 18 regressions and store their intercepts in a vector. 
Something like this

```
      Port_1=inter(1)+Beta1(Market)+Beta2(SMB)+Beta3(HML)+Beta3(WXO)+e
      Port_2=inter(2)+Beta1(Market)+Beta2(SMB)+Beta3(HML)+Beta3(WXO)+e
      Port_18=inter(18)+Beta1(Market)+Beta2(SMB)+Beta3(HML)+Beta3(WXO)+e
```

I want these 18 intercepts to be stored in a vector. I can do it individually. But If there is a way to do with coding that will help me a lot of time.

Comment: If you are using least-squares method, then this can easily be done with linear algebra.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Your question is unclear (read the above link), but here's a general approach to the issue: http://edinbr.org/edinbr/2016/05/11/may-Hadley-Update2-PostingTalk.html

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I have edited my question. I'm fairly newbie to R, I do not quite understand those links contents. :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider `vapply()`, a variant of `lapply()` that allows specification of the output here being atomic numeric vector (length of 1). However, first, you need to merge the tables by `Date` field and then create a list of *Port* formulas (assuming that's the needed underlying data). Below runs linear regression, `lm`, but adjust to actual model which might require adjusting intercept extraction:

```
data <- merge(Table_01, Table_02, by="Date")

ports <- colnames(Table_01)[2:ncol(Table_01)]    
formulas <- paste(ports, "~ Market + SMB + HML + WXO")

intercepts <- vapply(formulas, function(i) { 
                          output <- lm(i, data)
                          coef(output)["(Intercept)"]
                     }, numeric(1))
```